# Remove Google form options once they have been selected

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I am trying to make a simple form in Google Forms, that is used to book an appointment. User gets prompted with a list of available dates. How would I go for setting it up so that once a user (or certain amount of users) chooses a desired date, that date is no longer available?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still actual, but just in case for someone else trying to find a solution - [there](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator-2/mnhoinjhhhafgieggnhjekliaodnkigj) is an add-on for Google Forms, called "Choice Eliminator 2"